# Android Studio - Room query different result than expected

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm having a difficult time understanding why does ***the same query*** on ***the same database*** is correct on my local testing environment (my computer) and is wrong over my device/emulator.

The database is literally the same (copied from emulator to computer).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name, max(date_col) as date_col, value FROM tbl
    WHERE date_col <= '2021-06-30'
    GROUP BY name
    UNION 
    SELECT name, min(date_col) as date_col, value FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY date_col DESC
)
GROUP BY name
```

The schema for the table is `(id, date_col, name, value)`.

What I'm trying to do is select all the rows with the nearest date to the supplied date. I'm not quite sure that this is the best way of doing it so any suggestions are welcomed

When trying this query in my computer (SQLITE v3.27.2) it works as intended and when testing on a device/emulator (Tried multiple API levels such as 23, 27, 28) they all failed.

Edit:
Table data:

```
|name |date_col  |value|
|-----|----------|-----|
|NAME6|2021-06-29|71   |
|NAME7|2021-06-29|80   |
|NAME1|2021-06-29|2925 |
|NAME4|2021-06-29|182.0|
|NAME2|2021-06-29|365  |
|NAME3|2021-06-29|81.0 |
|NAME5|2021-06-29|0.25 |
|NAME7|2021-06-27|81.0 |
|NAME1|2021-06-27|3000 |
|NAME5|2021-06-01|0.35 |
|NAME6|2021-06-01|68.0 |
|NAME5|2021-06-28|0.15 |
```

Results on device (for date 2021-06-28):

```
|name |date_col  |value|
|-----|----------|-----|
|NAME1|2021-06-27|3000 |
|NAME2|2021-06-29|365.0|
|NAME3|2021-06-29|81.0 |
|NAME4|2021-06-29|182.0|
|NAME5|2021-06-01|0.35 |
|NAME6|2021-06-01|68.0 |
|NAME7|2021-06-27|81.0 |
```

Results on computer (for date 2021-06-28):

```
|name |date_col  |value|
|-----|----------|-----|
|NAME1|2021-06-27|3000 |
|NAME2|2021-06-29|365.0|
|NAME3|2021-06-29|81.0 |
|NAME4|2021-06-29|182.0|
|NAME5|2021-06-28|0.15 |
|NAME6|2021-06-01|68.0 |
|NAME7|2021-06-27|81.0 |
```

As you can see, in this example the difference is with name5, it should be 0.15 but on device for some reason its 0.35.

What could be the reason for these differences?

Thank you very much!

Comment: SELECT * with GROUP BY does not make sense. Also what do you mean by *failed*? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I tried to do the SELECT * from in order to use a GROUP BY for the union (to get only one row per name), I'll update my question now to better explain what I mean by fail. Thank you for your answer, I'll test it and keep you posted

Comment: Why 2021-06-27 for NAME1 and not 2021-06-29?

Comment: Because at 2021-06-28 the latest NAME1 row was at 2021-06-27 with 3000 (it as if it didn't already existed) I'm sorry if this is confusing, please let me know if there's anything I can do to make it clearer. The purpose of this query is to get the latest user statistics at a certain date.

Comment: Do you mean that if there are 2 rows with the same distance from the 2021-06-27 you want the date that is less than 2021-06-27?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, yes. basically select the "latest" row existing for a given name than is below a given date

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite allows statements with `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY`, but the resulting rows are arbitrary.

If you want to use this in lower API levels, you can't use window functions which would easily solve the problem like this:

```
SELECT name, date_col, value 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY name 
              ORDER BY date_col < '2021-06-28' DESC,
                       abs(strftime('%s', date_col) - strftime('%s', '2021-06-28'))
                       
            ) rn
  FROM tbl
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name;
```

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.date_col, t1.value 
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.date_col = (
  SELECT t2.date_col 
  FROM tbl t2
  WHERE t2.name = t1.name 
  ORDER BY date_col < '2021-06-28' DESC,
           abs(strftime('%s', t2.date_col) - strftime('%s', '2021-06-28'))
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4f377761a924897784f1a1ba6cd3faf9).

Comment: Your answer already makes the results consistent, the first query works better for my case however if for example I try it with '2021-06-14', I get correct results. NAME5, 2021-06-01, 0.35. But if I try it with '2021-06-15', NAME5 is now 2021-06-28, 0.15 (Because of the order by I suppose)

Comment: I suspect you entered a wrong link for the demo?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It seems like its working very well for now :) (Also I did a small adjustment, changed to <= ). I realize its a bit strange to always select before the given date if exists and if not select from the nearest existing after the given date. But its important that it will function this way because this is user statistics which he can go back in time (in the app) and change at any given time. Anyways thank you again. now I just need to learn these awesome tricks.